# Reactor 3.x: is there an operator for throttleLatest (conflate)?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2, project-reactor, reactor, reactive-streams

In rx-java 2.x there is an operator named **throttleLatest** that conflates incoming events based on a given time:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/5979

**Is there a similar operator in Reactor 3?**
Or is it possible to get the same behaviour from combining other operators?

Answer (score 1):

No, currently as of reactor-core 3.2.0/3.1.9 there is no such operator.